# d3..js : adding texts to nodes and links using incoming JSON data of varying size

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

My JSON data is as follows:

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([
["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264, "1374903"],
["node/1061", "node/21373542", "Agent", "Customer", "530848.0", 1, 3000, "529502"],
["node/10750", "node/59648369", "Agent", "Customer", "1454228.0", 1, 120, "1454118"],
["node/10750", "node/78569210", "Agent", "Customer", "1425251.0", 1, 234, "1421416"],
["node/10750", "node/96726118", "Agent", "Customer", "1376239.0", 1, 434, "1376152"],
["node/10946829", "node/11190", "Customer", "Agent", "1409620.0", 20, 3380, "1406665"]...])
```

The length of the array of array is nt fixed but format stays the same.

Below is the link to the working JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/user/vishy1988/fiddles/

The above code runs fine on my system. but for some reason I cannot get it to run on JSfiddle. the code generates the below graph.

[image: node graph]

This is how I iterate through the above array and make the data for the graph:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(IDData);
   var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
   var startnodes = [];
   var endnodes = [];
   var startnodetype = [];
   var endnodetype = [];
   var PayTime = [];
   var TXN_COUNT = [];
   var Total_Amt = [];
   var SendTime = [];
   galData.map(function(e, i) {
   startnodes.push(e[0]);
   endnodes.push(e[1]);
   startnodetype.push(e[2]);
   endnodetype.push(e[3]);
   PayTime.push(e[4]);
   TXN_COUNT.push(e[5]);
Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
SendTime.push(e[7]);
 });
var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime);
makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);

 });
```

The createnodes function which creates the data necessary to render a graph is as follows:

```
function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype,  PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime) {
     var node_set = d3.set();
     var links = [];
     var nodetype = d3.set();
     startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
        var tgt = endnodes[i];
        node_set.add(src);
        node_set.add(tgt);
        links.push({
        source: src,
        target: tgt,
         value: 1
     });
   });

  var d3GraphData = {
     nodes: node_set.values().map(function(d) {
     return {
        id: d,
        group: 1
       }
   }),
   links: links
    }


   return d3GraphData;

};
```

Also need  to calculate below elements and add them to

```
 d3graphdata
```

Below should be the Node text on hovering over the nodes:

```
      startnodetype, //node text on hover
      endndodetype,  // node text on hover
```

below is the block of link text on hovering over the links:

```
      PayTime,       //
      TXN_COUNT,      block of text when hovering over links
      Total_Amt, 
      SendTime      //
```

Below is the code I am using for makegraph and inspired by this force directed graph from the d3 library:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

```
function makeGraph(selector, d3GraphData) {
  var svg = d3.select(selector),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3GraphData.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.group);
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(d3GraphData.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(d3GraphData.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

}
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
                                <meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Main Page </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='graphlogic.js')}}"></script>

</head>


<form action = "{{url_for('enter_ID')}}" method = "POST">
                                <p>
                                Galactic_ID: <input type = "text" name = "Galactic_ID" />
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                                Phone_ID: <input type = "text" name = "Phone_ID" />
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                                ID_Card: <input type = "text" name = "ident_ID" />
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
                                </p>
<body>
                                <style>
.links line {
                                stroke: #999;
                                stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}
.nodes circle {
                                stroke: #fff;
                                stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.nodes circle {
                                stroke: #fff;
                          stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.tooltip {
                                position: absolute;
                background-color: white;
                max-width: 200px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-width: 1px;
                box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                pointer-events: none;
}
                                </style>
                                <svg id="Network_graph" width="960" height="600"></svg>


                                <script type="text/javascript">
var IDData = JSON.stringify({{data|safe}});
                                </script>

<div id = "graph"></div>




</body>
</html>
```

In the above  makegraph code , I need  to add "hover" function for nodes and links which will display the necessary texts while hovering over nodes and links.

Brand new in Javascript  and d3.js.

Comment: Get a 404 when I go to your link. if you see this JSON Data for instance:

           ["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264, "1374903"]
Startnodetype is Agent and endnodetype is Customer.Those properties need to be added to the node and rest to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the data (node type) to the node object in order to be used later.

Here  is the example for your CreateNodes function.The object has a propertiw type. Note I am using a ES6 set instead of d3.set:

```
function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime) {
  var node_set = new Set();
  var links = [];
  var nodetype = d3.set();
  startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt = endnodes[i];
    node_set.add({id:src, type:startnodetype[i]});
    node_set.add({id:tgt, type:endnodetype[i]});
    links.push({
      source: src,
      target: tgt,
      paytime:PayTime[i],
      value: 1 
    });
  });

  startnodetype.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt_type = endnodetype[i];
    nodetype.add(src);
    nodetype.add(tgt_type);
  });

  var d3GraphData = {
    nodes: [...node_set.values()].map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        type: d.type,
        group: 1
      }
    }),
    links: links,
    nodetype: nodetype.values().map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        group: 1
      }
    })
  }
  return d3GraphData;

};
```

Then you can use the data to fill the tool tip. I decided to use a div for the tool tip. You have more control of the tool tip appearance that way. I create the tooltip div on the fly:

```
//$(document).ready(function() {

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                            .append("div")
                            .attr("class","tooltip")
                            .style("opacity", 0);

  console.log(IDData);
  var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
```

Then when you add the node. You can add events for mouseover and update the tooltip div:

```
    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.group);
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        tooltip.transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("opacity", .8);
                        tooltip.html(d.id +"<p/>type:" + d.type)
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")                 
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
                })
    .on(...
```

Working [JSFiffdle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6ycuoyo/16/).

You can use the same method for the links tool tips.

Comment: hi , thanks a ton. what was the script src used for the tooltip? If I use 
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> then it is not compatible with the other functions that I have in there.

Comment: Your code was using D3 V4: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes. with that d3 v4 though , i am getting tooltip not defined error. So , I am trying to 2 use both d3.v3 and d3.v4 script src , but still no luck.

Comment: You should only use D3 V4, Tootip is a div created on the fly. I updated my answer.

Comment: why is the document.ready function in the fiddle enclosed under // //?

Comment: This is a Jquery function. I was just removing the Jquery dependency. Depending where the script is located, you no not need to wait for the doc ready event.

Comment: one last thing. I have updated the fiddle with the link text:
https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/t6ycuoyo/21/

Everything works well but the "Amount" quantity remains undefined while hovering over the link. Even though it is not blank in the JSON data , it appears undefined.

Comment: It was a small typo. total_amt (JS is case sensitive_) (https://jsfiddle.net/t6ycuoyo/24/)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Much appreciated.

Comment: Is it Possible to add different colors for different nodetypes? And nodetypes are at the JSON level.

Comment: You can change the style based on the d.type:
https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_style

You just need to have one style for each type.

Comment: Nice. That was easy.

Comment: Hi , I have been observing that sometimes there are a few nodes that are not connected with the above code. Any idea why?